# How to use a timer in a MasterPage using UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel, master-pages

I've got a problem with a timer inside a UpdatePanel. I want to set a countdown (35 mins) and when I press a button, it will start the countdown, but nothing happens when I click it. It's inside a content page, btw.

ASP code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="container">
<div style="position:fixed; border:dotted 2px; z-index:1">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTiempo" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i><asp:Label ID="lbMins" CssClass="h2" runat="server" Text="35" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lbPts" runat="server" CssClass="h2" Font-Bold="true">:</asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbSecs" CssClass="h2" runat="server" Text="00" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEmpezar" runat="server" Text="Empezar" OnClick="btnEmpezar_Click"/>
        <asp:Timer ID="tmTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tmTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

And here's the C# code:

```
int mins = 35;
int secs = 0;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmTimer.Enabled = false;
}

protected void tmTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
    }

    if (secs < 10)
        lbSecs.Text = "0" + secs;
    else
        lbSecs.Text = "" + secs;

    if (mins < 10)
        lbMins.Text = "0" + mins;
    else
        lbMins.Text = "" + mins;

    if (secs == 0 && mins == 0)
    {
        lbMins.Text = "00";
        lbSecs.Text = "00";

        tmTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    secs--;

    upTiempo.Update();
}

protected void btnEmpezar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is something missing? Should I kill myself?

Answer (score 0):

Killing yourself wouldn't help much now, would it?

Anyways, your timer resides inside the update panel.
If you call `upTiempo.Update();`, the entire panel is reloaded, including the timer. The timer is disabled by default, that's why nothing happens after the first tick event is fired.

Set it up like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="tmTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tmTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<div class="container">
<div style="position:fixed; border:dotted 2px; z-index:1">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTiempo" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i><asp:Label ID="lbMins" CssClass="h2" runat="server" Text="35" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lbPts" runat="server" CssClass="h2" Font-Bold="true">:</asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbSecs" CssClass="h2" runat="server" Text="00" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEmpezar" runat="server" Text="Empezar" OnClick="btnEmpezar_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

This way, when the panel is reloaded, the timer remains untouched and keeps running as expected.

Hope this helps

Comment: Well... It ididn't work... I added a break point and when the page loads, it sends me to the master page C# code...

Comment: Thanks for helping, by the way

Comment: Alright, I couldn't identify underlying problems ;) but still, keep your timers outside of your update panels

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found a solution... I just stored the mins and secs values into a Session variable, so...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["mins"] = mins;
        Session["secs"] = secs; 

        tmTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void tmTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mins = int.Parse(Session["mins"].ToString());
    secs = int.Parse(Session["secs"].ToString());

    if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
    }

    if (secs < 10)
        lbSecs.Text = "0" + secs;
    else
        lbSecs.Text = "" + secs;

    if (mins < 10)
        lbMins.Text = "0" + mins;
    else
        lbMins.Text = "" + mins;

    if (secs == 0 && mins == 0)
    {
        lbMins.Text = "00";
        lbSecs.Text = "00";

        tmTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    secs--;

    upTiempo.Update();

    Session["mins"] = mins;
    Session["secs"] = secs;
}
```